# Can i make site myself?

Tags: wordpress

I like [this Wordpress template](http://themeforest.net/item/berg-multipurpose-onepage-multipage-template/12060911)

Can I make a working site from it myself - I need the same result like this template, would it be as beautiful?
I am novice, and didn't try it yet.

Comment: I suggest that you rather spend the money and buy the theme. In all honesty, you are not going to achive your goal with no or very limited knowledge of php, css and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, after a lot of practice and studying ofcourse. If you really need a proper working website for a company in short terms, you might better forget to attempt. If it is as a hobby, get to work with your best [friend](http://www.google.com).

But questions like these are not really apriciated on Stack Overflow. You are asking about our opinion on a personal matter. Best of luck anyway!